# How to get a Stencil component parameter synchronously and set it without rerendering the component?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, prop, stenciljs

I have a Stencil component that contains a not-Prop member variable: `private _zIndex`.  This variable's value can be set by calling a `Method() setZIndex( zIndex : number );` or it can change when the component does its thing internally.  I need a way to get the current value of this variable externally. I tried creating a Method() that just `return this._zIndex`.  The problem is that this method must be async since I get a warning if it is not:

```
External @Method() getZIndex() should return a Promise or void.  
Consider prefixing the method with async,  Next minor release will error.
```

I don't want the getZIndex() function to be asynchronous so my other option is to make a `Prop( { mutable: true } ) _zIndex`.  If I do that, then I can set/get the variable's value however now anytime I set the value of the variable, it forces stencil to rerender my component. This can be slow because my component is large and contains lots of nested components.

Is there a way I can either:

- get the value of a private variable externally without it being done asynchronously?

or

- is there a way to make a Prop not force a re-render when its value is changed?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Stencil `@Method` are expected to be async. There are some rationales for this decision here: https://stenciljs.com/docs/methods

2 - You can determine when you want a component to re-render by using the `componentWillUpdate()` lifecycle method: https://stenciljs.com/docs/component-lifecycle#rendering-state

To prevent `_zIndex` from triggering a re-render, you'd want to store the previous value, and compare it to the current:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
  if (this._zIndex !== this.cachedZindex) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: There is no mention in the doc's that componentWillUpdate() should return a boolean.  Also in the typescript definition files, function is defined this way:

`abstract componentWillUpdate?: () => Promise<void> | void;`